# How to copy multiple specified files in eshell

Tags: eshell

The following works in a separate program terminal window (to copy multiple specified files in the same directory), but the command does not work in Eshell (**No such file or directory**).  Is there an alternative way of accomplishing this task using Eshell?

```
cp /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.sources/emacs/\
{buffer.c,\
buffer.h,\
dispextern.h,\
keyboard.c,\
nsterm.m,\
w32term.c,\
window.h,\
xdisp.c,\
xterm.c} \
/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs/src/
```

**Background**:  What did I try?  I blocked and copied the above text and pasted/yanked it at the command prompt in an `*eshell*` buffer, and then I pressed the enter/return key.  What happened?  I received an error message:  **No such file or directory**.

Comment: You can use lisp forms such as `directory-files`, e.g., `ls (directory-files "~" t "\\..*")` for an example. The [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Expansion) claims that the globbing syntax is similar to zshell. But, it seems that this does not include your expression.

Comment: @Tobias -- thank you for the suggestion to use an `elisp` form to create the list of files to be copied.  I posted a draft answer which can be accepted in about 48 hours.  I'd be happy to give you credit for answering the question if you would like to post a variation, or a different solution if anything else comes to mind.

Comment: Now I have learned that there is actually much more. If eshell reckognizes a file name pattern the or-operator works. Try: `ls ~/.*(bash|profile)*`  The leading `~/.` or anything that makes clear that you mean a file name pattern and not a lisp form is important. So your example should read `cp /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.sources/emacs/(buffer.c|buffer.h|dispextern.h|keyboard.c|nsterm.m|w32term.c|window.h|xdisp.c|xterm.c) ~/Desktop/emacs/src/`

Comment: @Tobias -- that doesn't seem to work with the default eshell settings:  *Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Unknown predicate character ‘b’") signal(error ("Unknown predicate character ‘b’")) error("Unknown predicate character `%c'" 98) eshell-parse-modifiers() . . .*

Comment: Ah yes. You have to add something at the end of the group expression `(...)` else this becomes a predicate. E.g., add an empty string `''` such that the expression beomes `(...)''`. Sorry. This happend because your example requires some blind-walking;-). This is also the reason why I posted this as a comment and not as a solution. My simple `ls`-example worked because of the trailing star `*`.

Comment: Yes, your example now works:  `cp /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.sources/emacs/(buffer.c|buffer.h|dispextern.h|ke‌​yboard.c|nsterm.m|w32term.c|window.h|xdisp.c|xterm.c)'' ~/Desktop/emacs/src/`  :)  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eshell accepts ksh-like syntax. Amog others you can specify a group of files by `(file1|file2|...|fileN)`. But, that is a bit tricky since parentheses also indicate lisp forms to be evaluated (for an example see the [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22458/2370) by [lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2287/lawlist)).

Furthermore, there are also predicates in parenthesis. The predicates come as last thing of a path specification.
Example:

```
echo *(/)
```

prints a list of directories.

To differentiate groups from lisp forms and predicates you must append something to the group string. Maybe, you want to append something anyway.
Example:

```
echo (file1|file2).txt
```

As a last resort you can just append an empty string `''`:

```
echo (file1|file2)''
```

The solution to the original-posters problem would be:

```
cp /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.sources/emacs/(buffer.c|buffer.h|dispextern.h|ke‌​‌​yboard.c|nsterm.m|w32term.c|window.h|xdisp.c|xterm.c)'' ~/Desktop/emacs/src/
```

---

In the following I cite the help strings `eshell-predicate-help-string` and `eshell-modifier-help-string` as an add-on to the answer.
Maybe the modifiers and predicates are not so well known even if they are a quite powerful system. (At least I did not know about them until I answered this question.)

Eshell predicate quick reference:

```
  -  follow symbolic references for predicates after the `-'
  ^  invert sense of predicates after the `^'

FILE TYPE:
  /  directories              s  sockets
  .  regular files            p  named pipes
  *  executable (files only)  @  symbolic links

  %x  file type == `x' (as by ls -l; so `c' = char device, etc.)

PERMISSION BITS (for owner/group/world):
  r/A/R  readable    s  setuid
  w/I/W  writable    S  setgid
  x/E/X  executable  t  sticky bit

OWNERSHIP:
  U               owned by effective uid
  u(UID|'user')   owned by UID/user
  g(GID|'group')  owned by GID/group

FILE ATTRIBUTES:
  l[+-]N                 +/-/= N links
  a[Mwhms][+-](N|'FILE') access time +/-/= N months/weeks/hours/mins/secs
             (days if unspecified) if FILE specified,
             use as comparison basis; so a+'file.c'
             shows files accessed before file.c was
             last accessed
  m[Mwhms][+-](N|'FILE') modification time...
  c[Mwhms][+-](N|'FILE') change time...
  L[kmp][+-]N            file size +/-/= N Kb/Mb/blocks

EXAMPLES:
  *(^@)         all non-dot files which are not symlinks
  .#*(^@)       all files which are not symbolic links
  **/.#*(*)     all executable files, searched recursively
  ***/*~f*(-/)  recursively (though not traversing symlinks),
        find all directories (or symlinks referring to
        directories) whose names do not begin with f.
  e*(*Lk+50)    executables 50k or larger beginning with 'e'
```

Eshell modifier quick reference:

```
FOR SINGLE ARGUMENTS, or each argument of a list of strings:
  E  evaluate again
  L  lowercase
  U  uppercase
  C  capitalize
  h  dirname
  t  basename
  e  file extension
  r  strip file extension
  q  escape special characters

  S       split string at any whitespace character
  S/PAT/  split string at each occurrence of PAT

FOR LISTS OF ARGUMENTS:
  o  sort alphabetically
  O  reverse sort alphabetically
  u  uniq list (typically used after :o or :O)
  R  reverse list

  j       join list members, separated by a space
  j/PAT/  join list members, separated by PAT
  i/PAT/  exclude all members not matching PAT
  x/PAT/  exclude all members matching PAT

  s/pat/match/  substitute PAT with MATCH
  g/pat/match/  substitute PAT with MATCH for all occurrences

EXAMPLES:
  *.c(:o)  sorted list of .c files
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a draft solution based on the helpful comment of @Tobias, which suggests the possibility of using an `elisp` form to create the list of files to be copied.  [I added the `-p` argument to preserve the filestamps of the files being copied.]

I may decide to either turn this into a saved function with arguments for the root directory and a list for the files within that directory; or, I may decide to create a new special eshell function named something like `eshell/cp` which can do regular copy stuff or something special if it finds a familiar form of arguments.  [I can't accept my own answer until about 36 hours after posting a question and it's only been about 12 hours so far, so I'll check back.]

```lisp
cp -p
  (let* (
      result
      (basename (file-name-as-directory "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.sources/emacs/"))
      (files '(buffer.c buffer.h dispextern.h keyboard.c nsterm.m w32term.c window.h xdisp.c xterm.c)) )
    (dolist (file files)
      (push (concat basename (format "%s" file)) result))
    result) /Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs/src/
```